# Randomly selecting items from a list without repeating

Tags: python, random

**I was given this problem:** Program that randomly shows 53 cards one by one every 5 seconds or so without repeating them.

My code right now looks extremly basic as Im still trying to figure out how to make it work. I have managed to randomly print the items from the list without repeating but when it runs out of options i get an error. Here's a part of my code:

```
let = ['CARD 1','CARD2','CARD 3']#Theres only 3 cards until i figure how to do it
if var=='iniciar' or 'INICIAR':
  while True:
    random.choice(let)
    while len(let):
    print let.pop()
    import time
    time.sleep(.5)
```

Can any of you figure out how to do it or have an example I can use?

Comment: Can you fix the indentation?

Comment: What you are after is `random.shuffle`.

Comment: If you do not want to shuffle the original list, use `random.sample`

Answer (score 3):

You can let this work with `random.shuffle`:

```
import random
import time

let = ['CARD 1','CARD2','CARD 3']

new_let = list(let)
random.shuffle(new_let)
for card in new_let:
    print(card)
    time.sleep(.5)
```

or we can sample:

```
import random
import time

let = ['CARD 1','CARD2','CARD 3']

new_let = random.sample(let, k=53)
for card in new_let:
    print(card)
    time.sleep(.5)
```

Here `k=53` is the number of elements we sample, so we can change the parameter.

It also is better to use a `for` loop, and iterate over the list, instead of popping and destroying (usually it is better to not change data structures unless you need to).

Note that the:

```
if var=='iniciar' or 'INICIAR':
```

should be:

```
if var == 'iniciar' or var == 'INICIAR':
```

since otherwise the condition is always true: `or` checks the truthiness of both operands, and the truthiness of a non-empty string is `True`.

Comment: I'd use `random.sample` not to mutate the original data.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon: we can also make a copy of the list, but yes, the two are more declarative.